# Origin of "don't have a coronary"?

Tags: etymology, idioms, history

I'm assuming the entire phrase would be "don't have a coronary occlusion" meaning "don't have a heart attack." I haven't been able to find anything useful regarding when or where it might have originated.

Comment: Where have you looked? (This saves us wasting time and effort looking in the same places!)

Comment: In addition to what Trev asks (where you've looked for an answer) you could give us more about where the question originates - which is to say, where did you hear this?  Your assumption sounds reasonable, but this is not (specifically) a very common expression.   "Don't have a ___" *is* quite common, and I expect its origin is much older than this specific version.

Comment: I would guess it's a warmed-over version of "don't have a conniption/fit".  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=don%27t+have+a+conniption%2C+don%27t+have+a+fit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20have%20a%20conniption%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20have%20a%20fit%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

It has the same meaning as "Don't have a heart attack" and is used in a way to tell the other person to calm down and not get worked up.

The earliest examples I found are in snippets from 1982 books.

*[Immediate Release](http://books.google.com/books?id=w7yHAAAAIAAJ)* - Page 41 - William Mathewson - 1982 - Snippet view:

> "Of course not, Stanley," said Lynette patiently. **"Don't have a coronary."**
>
> "Stan," Tony said, "look, I got to get back to shore."
>
> "Yeah, yeah," said Stanley.

*[Marva Collins' Way](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=0874772354)* - Page 135 - Marva Collins, Civia Tamarkin - 1982 - Snippet view:

> "Don't give me that 'I'm finished' business," she said. "We are never finished in life. We don't ever stand around idly or sit with our hands folded, acquiescing. God isn't finished with you and I'm not either."
>
> "Okay, okay, **don't have a coronary**," Gary said, sitting down and holding up his palms in surrender.
>
> Marva laughed. "I love your spunk. Don't ever let anyone break your will. Since you are finished, why don't you let us read your theme?"

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to [this google NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Don%27t%20have%20a%20coronary,%20don%27t%20have%20a%20coronary&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), it seems to have appeared in 1960 and to have peaked in the early 70's. Perhaps it was popularized by a TV show of the time?

[image]